# Lua crashing for no apparent reason

Tags: lua

We have Lua integrated into a project but we've found an odd test case that crashes consistently on ARM:

```
data = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};

function OnTick(_object)

    local params = {};

    return 1;
end
```

Here is the basics of how the function is being called from C++:

```
lua_getglobal(Lua, function_name->c_str()); // Push function name that we want to call onto the stack
if (lua_isnil(Lua, -1))
{
    // Error
    lua_pop(Lua, 1);
    return -1;
}
lua_pushlightuserdata(Lua, (void*)object);  // Push the reference object onto the stack

if (lua_pcall(Lua, 1, 1, 0) != 0)
{
    // Error
    lua_pop(Lua, 1);
    return -1;
}

lua_pop(Lua, 1);
return 1;
```

OnTick crashes after being called around 5 times.

Lua appears to be crashing when the garbage collector tries to clean up. Anyone else come across something like this and solved it?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would cause Lua to crash, but there may very well be something in the code you *didn't* show us that would. A lot more context needed for this to be an answerable question.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details on how its being called from c++

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this issue, the client code was corrupting the Lua state